# Test if python Counter is contained in another Counter

Tags: python, algorithm, counter, inclusion

How to test if a python [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is *contained* in another one using the following definition:

> *A Counter `a` is contained in a Counter `b` if, and only if, for every key `k` in `a`, the value `a[k]` is less or equal to the value `b[k]`. The `Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 1})` is contained in `Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 2})` but it is not contained in `Counter({'a': 2, 'c': 2})`.*

I think it is a poor design choice but in python *2.x* the comparison operators (`<`, `<=`, `>=`, `>`) do not use the previous definition, so the third Counter is considered *greater-than* the first. In python *3.x*, instead, `Counter` is an *unorderable type*.

Comment: You should properly define "contained" to avoid confusion.

Comment: `Counter` doesn't actually support comparison operators.

Comment: @JimDennis: We're supposed to be considering the Counter as a multiset, and that attempt doesn't take into account the multiplicity of elements.

Comment: @JimDennis: No, I don't want to check if all the keys are present, I want to check also the multiplicity as user2347112 said: *A Counter a is contained in a Counter b if, and only if, for every key k in a, the value a[k] is less or equal to the value b[k].*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Update 2023: `Counter` supports [rich comparison operators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter:%7E:text=rich%20comparison%20operators) as of python `3.10`, so this works:

```py
container <= contained
```

---

Historical answer for python < 3.10:

The best I came up with is to convert the definition i gave in code:

```
def contains(container, contained):
    return all(container[x] >= contained[x] for x in contained)
```

But if feels strange that python don't have an *out-of-the-box* solution and I have to write a function for every operator (or make a generic one and pass the comparison function).

Comment: Agreed, given that `Counter` gives a couple of multiset-like operations, it's surprising it doesn't offer a `subset of` equivalent. I'd expect to just be able to do `counter_a <= counter_b` - Either way, this seems like the best solution possible to me.

Answer (score 15):

While `Counter` instances are not comparable with the `<` and `>` operators, you can find their difference with the `-` operator. The difference never returns negative counts, so if `A - B` is empty, you know that `B` contains all the items in `A`.

```
def contains(larger, smaller):
    return not smaller - larger
```

Comment: I considered giving this answer, but I decided against it because this doesn't short-circuit and wastes a bunch of time and space building the Counter. Also, it has to iterate through *both* Counters due to how `-` handles negative counts in the second argument. The solution based on `all` is much more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Another, fairly succinct, way to express this:

"Counter A is a subset of Counter B" is equivalent to `(A & B) == A`.

That's because the intersection (`&`) of two Counters has the counts of elements common to both. That'll be the same as `A` if every element of `A` (counting multiplicity) is also in `B`; otherwise it will be smaller.

Performance-wise, this seems to be about the same as the `not A - B` method proposed by Blckknght. Checking each key as in the answer of enrico.bacis is considerably faster.

As a variation, you can also check that the union is equal to the larger Counter (so nothing was added): `(A | B) == B`. This is noticeably slower for some largish multisets I tested (1,000,000 elements).

Comment: `collections.Counter("abc") & collections.Counter("b") == collections.counter("abc")` returns False, so this doesn't seem to work

Comment: That's because "abc" is not a subset of "b".

Answer (score 1):

For all the keys in smaller `Counter` make sure that no value is greater than its counterpart in the bigger `Counter`:

```
def containment(big, small):
    return not any(v > big[k] for (k, v) in small.iteritems())

>>> containment(Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 2}), Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 1}))
True
>>> containment(Counter({'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'b': 3}), Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 2}))
True
>>> print containment(Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 2}), Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c':1}))
False
>>> print containment(Counter({'a': 2, 'c': 2}), Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 1})
False
```

Comment: Which version of python are you using? In Python 2 it returns `True` for both the invocations, while in python 3 it throws an error because Counter is unorderable. Moreover you don't really need a function for that.

Comment: @enrico.bacis I copied it wrong before. It works fine on Py 2.7 I'm on. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: As I said in the question, the comparison operator only check the total number of elements in the counter. Try with my example: `Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 2}) >= Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 1})` gives `True` as expected, but `Counter({'a': 2, 'c': 2}) >= Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 1})` also gives `True` even if the right hand side is not *contained* in the left hand side.

Comment: @enrico.bacis I've added another check get around the case you mentioned.

Comment: Now it works but keep in mind that *not any( predicate )* is exactly the same as *all( not predicate )*, so the answer is semantically the same as my answer above ;)

Comment: @enrico.bacis True :D

Comment: Another couple of suggestions, you are using `.items()` to get also the value `v` while you should prefer `.iteritems()` which does not create an intermediate list but a generator, since you are not storing the values. You are also not using `v`. To be more efficient, you should use `not any(v > big[k] for (k, v) in small.iteritems())` or `not any(small[k] > big[k] for k in small)`.

Answer (score 1):

While of historical interest, all these answers are obsolete.
Counter class objects are in fact comparable
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I would write the actual code into your answer though instead of pasting a screenshot, otherwise it forces people to have to hand-type everything you've done here (versus just copy and pasting your code).